# Order DataFrame by row count of col1, and category

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I want to order this DataFrame by a given column field and the number of entries I have for this given field.

So let's say I have a very simple dataframe, looking something like this:

```
      name  age
0     Paul   12
1     Ryan   17
2  Michael  100
3     Paul   36
4     Paul   66
5  Michael   45
```

What I want as a result is something like

```
      name  age
0     Paul   12
1     Paul   36
2     Paul   66
3  Michael  100
4  Michael   45
5     Ryan   17
```

So I have 3 Paul's, so they come up first, then 2 Michael's, and finally only 1 Ryan.

Comment: Alternatively, use ordered categorical based on groupby name size

Comment: Can you explain why you need this ordering? Feels like an XY problem. Why can't you just use `groupby()`? You should generally be able to ungroup and reorder the output of whatever aggregation/summary/transform you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option: use `value_counts` to get the most frequent names, then set, sort, and reset the index:

```
x = list(df['name'].value_counts().index)
df.set_index('name').loc[x].reset_index()
```

returns

```
      name  age
0     Paul   12
1     Paul   36
2     Paul   66
3  Michael  100
4  Michael   45
5     Ryan   17
```

Answer (score 3):

Need to create a helper column to sort, in this case the `size` of the name groups. Add a `.reset_index(drop=True)` if you prefer a brand new RangeIndex, or keep as is if the original Index is useful.

Sorting does not change the ordering within equal values, so the first `'Paul'` row will always appear first within `'Paul'`

```
(df.assign(s = df.groupby('name').name.transform('size'))
   .sort_values('s', ascending=False)
   .drop(columns='s'))
```

#### Output

```
      name  age
0     Paul   12
3     Paul   36
4     Paul   66
2  Michael  100
5  Michael   45
1     Ryan   17
```

---

To allay fears raised in comments, this method **is** performant. Much more so than the above method. Plus you don't ruin your initial index.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
N = 10**6
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': np.random.randint(1, 10000, N),
                   'age': np.random.normal(0, 1, N)})

%%timeit 
(df.assign(s = df.groupby('name').name.transform('size'))
   .sort_values('s', ascending=False)
   .drop(columns='s'))
#500 ms ± 31.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit 
x = list(df['name'].value_counts().index)
df.set_index('name').loc[x].reset_index()
#2.67 s ± 166 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I would probably do the same here.

Comment: This is going to be slower and less scaleable than @BrendanCox's answer. `df.groupby(...)` does a sort by default, and you also do `.sort_values()` within each group, so it's going to be O(NlogN) or worse (O(N2)). There is no need to sort by anything, we only need to get counts.

Comment: @smci I'm not sorting within group. It's a single sort on the entire `DataFrame` after a cythonized calculation of group size. But I'll take your point that there's no need to sort the groups, so you can add `sort=False` to the groupby to get some improvement.

Comment: @smci please see the update, this method can be faster for a larger Frame with many groups

Comment: @ALollz what's your experience with transform('size')? I recently find it's somehow much much slower compared to df.join(df.groupby(cols).size, on=cols) when the group size is large

Comment: @MarkWang I haven't really paid attention to the difference, but I typically find `.transform('size')` to be fast enough that I haven't had to look. If there's a big difference you can reproduce, it might make for a good question.

Comment: @ALollz I was recently testing it on 1 million groups and 200mil rows. transform('size') failed miserably (like 10min long!) compared to join+groupby.size which takes ~15sec.

Comment: @MarkWang, ALollz can you guys both check and state your peak memory usage and max rows that this approach can handle, sounds like Mark is blowing out physical memory?

Answer (score 0):

The only change I added was the ability to sort by count of name, and by age.

```
    df['name_count'] = df['name'].map(df['name'].value_counts())
    df = df.sort_values(by=['name_count', 'age'], 
                        ascending=[False,True]).drop('name_count', axis=1)
    df.reset_index(drop=True)


        name    age
      0 Paul    12
      1 Paul    36
      2 Paul    66
      3 Michael 45
      4 Michael 100
      5 Ryan    17
```